# Android google map, Create a marker on click and immediately start dragging it

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently creating markers on long press on a google map in an android application.
I am also dragging those markers by doing the standard long press on a marker, so it lifts up and becomes dragable.
Both these things work fine. My issue is that when I keep pressing, after creating, and try to drag, the whole map is dragged and the marker is not moved.

This is obviously because the touch event is not started on this new marker, that I just created.
I have to lift my finger and then long press again to start dragging.

Is there a way to create a new marker and put it in the draggable state from the start, so I can long press to create and then slide it in position without having to end my long press and initiate a new one?

Comment: From a UX perspective I'd suggest to keep the marker static in the middle and drag only the map. This way the user does not have to "guess" where the marker is underneath the finger on the touchscreen. So all you have to do is to move the marker opposite of the map, for your case. But maybe this does not make sense in your application, as I dont know the full usecase. It really depends on the precision of the marker placement you want to achieve.

Comment: The default marker drag behavior for google map on android is that on long click it becomes dragable and in doing do it jumps some pixels above the clickpoint, so you can see it for your finger. That works nicely, since you can then easily place the marker anywhere in the currently visible map region.
By dragging the map, you can only reach the entire current area, if you start dragging by clicking the center of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example after creating a marker on long press the camera move listener updates the newly added marker's position to center.

The effect is what you described in that with the same long press (still holding down) the marker is created and is moved to camera center and map moves (along with marker) as usual.

On release of the long-press the marker is in its final position.

The idle listener is used to stop updating the newly added marker on camera moves. The marker can still be dragged on its own with the usual marker drag events (after the initial long press).

Applicable parts:

```
private Marker addedMarker;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    gMap = map;

    // ... other stuff...

    // on long press, create a marker at the press point, set the
    // the marker as draggable and record the new marker object.  
    // 
    // The camera moves will use the marker object to move it (while still
    // in long press mode).
    gMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng lng) {
            Log.d(TAG,"On long click");
            MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
            mo.position(lng).draggable(true);
            addedMarker = gMap.addMarker(mo);

        }
    });


   // If the added marker is still valid then update its position to 
   // camera center.
   gMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMove() {
            LatLng pos = gMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            if (addedMarker != null) {
                addedMarker.setPosition(pos);
            }
        }
    });


    // When the long-press drag stops then stop updating the newly added
    // marker.  The marker can still be dragged on its own as a result of
    // the draggable setting.
    gMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCameraIdle() {
              addedMarker = null;
          }
    });

}
```

---

Video of above - hard to tell but the marker is created while holding the long press and camera is moved while still holding the long press.

The long press is released and the marker comes to rest - and map moves continue to work as normal.  At this point the marker could be moved on its own with usual methods.

[image]

Comment: Interesting way of turning the problem on its head, and still let the map move (which I saw as the problem) but prevent the marker from moving with it. I will try it out right away.

Comment: Initially I thought this was a good solution, but I was a bit too quick to judge. The main issue with still moving the map during a drag, instead of the marker, is that when moving the marker, you can move it to all of the currently visible map, while dragging the map does not allow, but lets you move to outside the initially visible area.
Additionally, the standard dragging of a marker is behaving differently from this move-the-map method, so you end up with two very different behaviors.

Comment: Marking as answered again. It does in fact not answer the question, but it does demonstrate a valid, alternative, solution to the issue.